# ckeditor and mathtype in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i have already tried using getElementbyClassName  append class

I want to assign the values directly (without clicking the insert button). in ckeditor5 what is typed in math type

What I am expecting means I want to show the values directly based on what I typed in math in Angular.
Anyone has to resolve my problem.

Comment: In which angular hook do you use getElementsByClassName?

Comment: provide more information on your question

Comment: And getElementsByClassName is true not getElementbyClassName